# MyGet - NuGet Package Missing Content Directory

Tags: nuget, myget

I have a package that gets built on MyGet using a nuspec file (similar to the below). This has been working fine for a while but over the couple of days it seems that the `content` directory doesn't get created.

However, if I run `nuget pack` locally, it works fine and includes all of the files. I've attempted to make use of `contentFiles` but this doesn't work as the project is using the old `packages.config` method.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
      <id>MyProject</id>
      <version>1.4.0.2</version>
      <title>Project Description</title>
      <authors>0Neji</authors>
      <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
      <description>Description</description>
      <summary>Summary</summary>
      <releaseNotes>Release notes</releaseNotes>

      <language>en-GB</language>
      <dependencies>
        <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.6.1">
          <dependency id="UmbracoCms" version="7.6.4" />
          <dependency id="usync.snapshots" version="1.0.2.740" />
          <dependency id="SharpRaven" version="2.1.0" />
          <dependency id="Autofac.Mvc5" version="4.0.2" />
          <dependency id="Autofac.WebApi2" version="4.1.0" />
        </group>
      </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="robots.txt" target="content\robots.txt" />
  </files>
</package>
```

MyGet runs and builds the package successfully but when I download the project, the `content` directory is missing.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

On MyGet the nuget pack wil typically run against the .csproj (and not the .nuspec directly). Does that produce the same result on your machine?

Also does the build log mention the "pack" action being done using nuget pack or msbuild /t:Pack?

Could be this issue: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2372

Comment: Content dir is created either way. Can't see reference to either Nugent pack or the msbuild version in the build log so not entirely sure which is used. The issue looks to be a different problem, seems to be extra files, not less. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The build log should mention something along the lines of "Using '.........' to build NuGet package from file .........csproj". Wondering if that says nuget.exe or msbuild.

So: "when I download the project, the content directory is missing" vs "seems to be extra files, not less" - is MyGet producing more or less files?

Comment: Apologies, missed that, it appears to be using msbuild - `MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.1.1012.6693' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\bin'.` I've tried using `msbuild /t:Pack C:\MyProject.csproj` but get an error - `The target "pack" does not exist in the project`.

Comment: That probably means the build log contains "Using 'nuget....' to build NuGet package" and not "Using 'msbuild....' to build NuGet package" ?

Try packing with the latest NuGet.exe 4.1. If that produces the same result, thsi may be a bug report for the NuGet folks.

Comment: I can't see any other 'using' statements apart from the msbuild one. I'll see if I can get help from MyGet or the NuGet devs. Thanks again for your help.